# Using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to use `On Duplicate Key Update`.

My structure is I want to **ADD** new data and **UPDATE** table (in my student table with is imported by Excel) to my existing data. Some data in my table have existing emails and I want to just update the other columns. (with new values and those with null values are ignored in the new tables).

My email is an Unique foreign key and the rest of the data are bind.
The code doesn't work and it kept prompting ON has a syntax error.

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(   email                   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES  Users(email),
a varchar(50) null,
b varchar(50) null,
c varchar(50) null,
c varchar(50) null)


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Students](email, a, b, c, d)
select t2.email, t2.a, t2.b, t2.c, t2.d
from [dbo].[2020students$]
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = value(if(t2.a IS NOT NULL, a,t2.a)), a = value(t2.b), a = value(t2.c), a = value(t2.d)
```

Comment: `[dbo].[Students]` is SQL Server syntax. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is MySQL syntax. They cannot be combined. Please look carefully what DBMS you're using, and remove wrong tag.

Comment: Use `MERGE` for SQL Server. See the differences [here](https://geekyisawesome.blogspot.com/2014/09/doing-upsert-update-or-insert-if-new-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
insert into students(email, a, b, c, d)
select email, a, b, c, d
from `2020students$`
on duplicate key update 
    a = coalesce(values(a), a), 
    b = values(b), 
    c = values(c), 
    d = values(d)
```

This resolves the conflicts by updating values `b`, `c` and `d`. Special case is taken of `a`, that is updated only if the new value is not `null`.

This assumes that you are running MySQL - which is not obvious after all, because the use of square brackets and schema `dbo` look more like SQL Server syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I am running in SQL Server, does this on duplicate key update only works for Mysql?